# When String has replace() function why it does not have reverse() inbuilt?

Tags: java, replace, reverse

When we can directly use String replace function why not reverse? I know the immutable concept but the same way like replace, reverse can also work right?

When the below works fine,
String str="Java";
str.replace('j','a')

why java doesn't allow below
String str="Java";
str.reverse();

PS: I know other ways to reverse in java. but why the inbuilt is not there. Is there something java doesn't want to build? Why?

Comment: You can reverse a `String` using a `StringBuilder`.  I don't think there's any documentation about why the `String` class doesn't have a reverse method.

Comment: We can't tell you the exact reason that "they" did not provide a `reverse` method for `String`.  But >I< expect it is because real world applications rarely need to reverse strings.  And there `StringBuilder.reverse` if your application  is one of the 0.01% of real applications that actually need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

reverse will mean many thing in this situation like "hi hello how" if you want to reverse it than one may think like reversing be like "how hello hi" or "woh olleh ih". Thats why we need to develop our own method as per our need.

Comment: I think the only reasonable default implementation is to reverse character-by-character. A string is simply a sequence of characters. Words are a higher-level concept. But if one wants to reverse based on "words", then the obvious solution is to provide an overload that accepts a delimiter (a likely naive implementation would just `split`, reverse the array, then `join`). That would seem to cover most cases. However, since we can already reverse a string via `StringBuilder`, there does not seem to be enough of a reason for them to add a method to `String`.